# Using Element API to output Super Table fields

Tags: plugin-elementapi, plugin-supertable

I am building a feed using Element API. I am currently looping through Matrix blocks to get various data (based on the help from [this post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13118/how-do-you-use-the-element-api-plugin-to-output-matrix-blocks-for-an-entry?rq=1)). One of the matrix blocks contains a Super Table field, with various fields inside of that. Here is the relevant section of my Element API config file.

```
'transformer' => function(Entry $entry) {
  $contentBlocksArray = [];

     foreach ($entry->contentBlocks as $block){
       switch($block->type->handle) {

         case 'introText':
           $contentBlocksArray[] = [
             'introText' => [
               'body' => $block->body,
             ]
            ];
            break;

          case 'twoColumnText':
             $contentBlocksArray[] = [
               'twoColumnText' => [
                  'columnTextBlocks' => [
                      'icon' => $block->icon,
                      'text' => $block->text
                  ]
                ]
              ];
              break;
```

The first case in this switch works as expected. 'introText' is the Matrix box and 'body' is a plaintext field inside that block. The second case is where I'm having trouble. 'twoColumnText' is the Matrix block and 'columnTextBlocks' is a Super Table field with two plaintext fields. The api returns a response, but both 'icon' and 'text' = null.

I have also tried calling some of the functions as demonstrated in Super Tables docs [here](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/super-table/docs/guides/developer-examples) but no luck. I am by no means a php / laravel / etc developer, so I might be missing something that would be obvious to such a developer.

I suspect it's something similar to retrieving images where I have to loop through the Super Table fields, but I don't know what that syntax would look like.

Comment: Is it a static field? If so have you tried `$block->columnTextBlocks->icon`? If it's not a static field I can create an answer with how to loop through the rows

Comment: @RobinSchambach They weren't originally, but I changed them to static and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution I found. Define an empty array, then loop over it, providing whatever keys you want to return from the Super Table fields. Simply by looping over `$block->columnTextBlocks` (the handle of my Super Table field), Element API returns the information for the fields within the Super Table.

```
 case 'twoColumnText':

    $SuperTableRows = [];

    foreach ($block->columnTextBlocks as $row){
        $SuperTableRows[] = [
            'fieldHandle1' => $row->fieldHandle1,
            'fieldHandle2' => $row->fieldHandle2,
            'fieldHandle3' => $row->fieldHandle3
        ];
    }

    $contentBlocksArray[] = [
        'twoColumnText' => [
            'columnTextBlocks' => $SuperTableRows,
        ]
    ];

break;
```

If you need additional information about the Super Table fields, such as Placeholder text, field id's, etc. you can add a generic call to the Super Table field like so (using the same names as my previous code example):

```
$contentBlocksArray[] = [
    'twoColumnText' => [
        'generic' => $block->columnTextBlocks,
        'columnTextBlocks' => $SuperTableRows,
    ]
];
```

Now in Element API, the "generic" object includes a customFields array for each field within the Super Table. This only becomes available when you loop over the Super Table field, otherwise it would be `null`.

Here are some pictures of what the data from Element API looks like.

[image: Return Super Table fields data from Element API]

[image: Complete field data from Super Table field item in Element API]

Here is a simplified version:

```
'transformer' => function(Entry $entry) {
   $SuperTableRows = [];

   foreach ($entry->superTableFieldHandle as $row){
     $SuperTableRows[] = [
       'fieldHandle1' => $row->fieldHandle1,
       'fieldHandle2' => $row->fieldHandle2
     ];
   }


   return [
     'SuperTableRows' => $SuperTableRows
   ];
 },
```